# How to get around the 200 IP address rule limit in Azure Data Lake Storage firewall config?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

Iam trying to whitelist more that 3000 IP addresses with no ranges in the firewall rules for ADLS. Currently there is a limit of 200 IP address rules per storage acount. Is there a way to get around this limit?

Comment: Sounds like you should reconsider your architecture. Azure storage account network restrictions are not designed for complex or massive filtering. You should consider using a private endpoint for your storage account and building network-level controls through Azure networking features like VPNs, NSGs, Azure Firewall etc. I would start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/network-best-practices and continue with resources from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/

Comment: Thanks @bursson But its ADLS Gen 1 so it cannot have a private endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase the 200 IP address range. You can only request higher capacity and ingress limits by reaching to azure support.